# Using the same cursor twice via a button with java/android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have an android activity with a databasehelper file which I 'refer' to via cursor. The cursor fetches 1 row from the database for display on the activity. The MainActivity is as below.

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        get_data();     }


private void get_data() {
        Cursor dat = myDb.get_dat();
        cur_get(dat);   }

    private void cur_get(Cursor cursor) {

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                fir = cursor.getInt(0);                         

            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }       

    }
```

It works without problems and I get the 'fir' value.

But what I am  stuck with now is on how to repeat the process below via a button (via onclick method). Meaning, when the user click on the button, I want the whole process repeated to get a different another number. Moreover, I want to keep count of the amount of times the user does this.

I could not think of a method to do this. Would appreciate any ideas anyone can give me on this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 Cursor dat;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    get_data();     } 


private void get_data() { 
    Cursor dat = myDb.get_dat();
    cur_get(dat);   }

private void cur_get(Cursor cursor) {

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do { 
            fir = cursor.getInt(0);                         

        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    } 


final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {

             if (dat.moveToNext())
              {
                fir = dat.getInt(0);
              }


         } 
     }); 


}
```

Comment: I tried the method described, but there is an error at ')' of the line "if (dat.moveToNext()" that asks me to insert another ")" to complete the block statement. If I do, the dat and cursor variable becomes unrecognizable...

Comment: Just corrected the typos. The code is easy to understand, though, you just need to make your cursor a class variable.